# In elasticsearch how to filter specific inner objects based on certain condition which are not influencing actual query hits

Tags: elasticsearch

How to filter only the inner objects based on certain condition. For example, I have products stored in es. Based on certain fields I want to query the products, for example model and some other condition. But I want to list out name and description of the query results only in the language value passed.

Schema is as follows

```
PUT /product/
{"mappings":{"productTypeA":{"dynamic":"strict","properties":{"id":{"type":"keyword"},"model":{"type":"keyword"},"version":{"type":"keyword"},"launchDate":{"type":"date","format":"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword"}}},"names":{"type":"object","properties":{"locale":{"type":"keyword"},"value":{"type":"keyword"}}},"descriptions":{"type":"object","properties":{"locale":{"type":"keyword"},"value":{"type":"keyword"}}}}}}}
```

My Product 1

```
POST /product/productTypeA/1
{"id":"1","model":"modelA","version":"1.0","launchDate":"20190924T175212.057+0000","names":[{"locale":"en","value":"product one"},{"locale":"fr","value":"produit un"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt eins"}],"descriptions":[{"locale":"en","value":"product one description"},{"locale":"fr","value":"description du produit un"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt eins Beschreibung"}]}
```

My Product2

```
POST /product/productTypeA/2
{"id":"2","model":"modelA","version":"1.0","launchDate":"20190924T175212.057+0000","names":[{"locale":"en","value":"product two"},{"locale":"fr","value":"produit deux"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt zwei"}],"descriptions":[{"locale":"en","value":"product two description"},{"locale":"fr","value":"description du produit deux"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt zwei Beschreibung"}]}
```

I tried post_filter on the query as follows on the below mentioned products data

```
GET /product/productTypeA/_search
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"model":"modelA"}}]}},"post_filter":{"bool":{"should":{"term":{"names.locale":"fr"}}}}}
```

But my results has names and description in all languages where as I am expecting them for each query result only in French

```
{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":0.2876821,"hits":[{"_index":"product","_type":"productTypeA","_id":"2","_score":0.2876821,"_source":{"id":"2","model":"modelA","version":"1.0","launchDate":"20190924T175212.057+0000","names":[{"locale":"en","value":"product two"},{"locale":"fr","value":"produit deux"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt zwei"}],"descriptions":[{"locale":"en","value":"product two description"},{"locale":"fr","value":"description du produit deux"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt zwei Beschreibung"}]}},{"_index":"product","_type":"productTypeA","_id":"1","_score":0.2876821,"_source":{"id":"1","model":"modelA","version":"1.0","launchDate":"20190924T175212.057+0000","names":[{"locale":"en","value":"product one"},{"locale":"fr","value":"produit un"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt eins"}],"descriptions":[{"locale":"en","value":"product one description"},{"locale":"fr","value":"description du produit un"},{"locale":"de","value":"Produkt eins Beschreibung"}]}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter on "descriptions" you need to  change your mapping from object to [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).
Object type is stored as flat fields so it not possible to filter them
ex. when description is of type object fields under it are stored as description.locale etc..

Below query will return all modelA which have description in french and french description will be present in [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits)

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "model": "modelA"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "descriptions",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "descriptions.locale": "fr"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 1:

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "model": "modelA"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "descriptions",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "descriptions.locale": "fr"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want all products of ModelA, irrespective of it having description in French or not, But any way I can get only the french descriptions. Like for example, I have 10 products in Model A of which 5 have description in french and rest 5 in German only, my result set should have 10 but how will I get only 5 french description in inner hit?

Comment: I have added answer for above in EDIT1